# PLSQL error - I have a mistake in procedure

Tags: oracle, procedure

When execute the procedure show the mistake, I need help for the problem.

the message is:

"begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with"

the query is:

````
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SGRAPRE.USP_REP_SOLICITUDES_INGRESADAS(
cCURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
    
     OPEN cCURSOR FOR   
    
         SELECT  DISTINCT 
        te.EXPEDIENTE_ID,
        UPPER(mtp.DESCRIPCION) AS TIPO_PROCEDIMIENTO,
        MTP.TIPO_PROCEDIMIENTO_ID,
        UPPER(mtg.NOMBRE) AS TIPO_GRACIA,
        MTG.TIPO_GRACIA_ID,
        TO_CHAR(te.FECHA_APERTURA,'YYYY-MM-DD'),
        te.CODIGO AS EXPEDIENTE,
        TRIM(TS.APELLIDO_PATERNO)||' '||NVL(TS.APELLIDO_MATERNO,'')||' '||NVL(TS.NOMBRE ,'') AS NOMBRES_SOLICITANTE,    
        tis.EDAD_REGISTRO,
        ti.EDAD,
        ts.PAIS_NACIMIENTO_COD,
        UPPER(mu.DESCRIPCION) AS UBICACION,
        MU.UBICACION_ID, 
        te.JURIDICO_NRO_CONDENA AS NUMERO_CONDENA,
        ti2.FECHA_INGRESO,
        ti2.FECHA_SALIDA, 
        UPPER(mcp.DELITO )
        FROM TRS_EXPEDIENTE te 
        left join TRS_PROCEDIMIENTO_GRACIA tpg ON tpg.PROCEDIMIENTO_GRACIA_ID= te.PROCEDIMIENTO_GRACIA_ID 
        left join TRS_SOLICITANTE ts ON ts.SOLICITANTE_ID = te.SOLICITANTE_ID 
        left join TRS_INFORMACION_SOCIAL tis ON tis.EXPEDIENTE_ID =te.EXPEDIENTE_ID 
        left join MAE_UBICACION mu ON mu.UBICACION_ID = te.UBICACION_ID 
        left join MAE_TIPO_PROCEDIMIENTO mtp  ON mtp.TIPO_PROCEDIMIENTO_ID  =tpg.TIPO_PROCEDIMIENTO_ID 
        left join MAE_TIPO_GRACIA mtg ON mtg.TIPO_GRACIA_ID  = tpg.TIPO_GRACIA_ID 
        left join MAE_PROCEDIMIENTO_CENTRO mpc  ON mpc.TIPO_PROCEDIMIENTO_ID = mtp.TIPO_PROCEDIMIENTO_ID
        left join TRD_SENTENCIA ts2 ON ts2.EXPEDIENTE_ID  =te.EXPEDIENTE_ID 
        left join TRD_INGRESO ti2 ON ti2.SENTENCIA_ID = ts2.SENTENCIA_ID  
        left join TRD_INFRACCION ti ON ti.SENTENCIA_ID = ts2.SENTENCIA_ID 
        left join MAE_CODIGO_PENAL mcp ON mcp.CODIGO_PENAL_ID = ti.CODIGO_PENAL_ID 
        where te.ACTIVO =1
        AND ts2.ACTIVO =1
ORDER BY
    ts.NOMBRE ASC
    
 END;```


I solving the problem
````

Comment: That is not a PLSQL error message. It's a list of keywords. Please provide the **complete, exact error message** you are getting.

Comment: Also there should be a line number? The parser is expecting one of the listed keywords.  Probably this is a typo and may get closed.

Answer (score 1):

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoQZM.png)

Isn't semicolon missing?
This should resolve the syntax error and allow the procedure to be created successfully